# How Filter dataframe with dictionary in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

My sample DataFrame is:

| file | Voucher_stand |
| --- | --- |
| 90.txt | SCA |
| 90.txt | SCB |
| 60.txt | WFA |
| 60.txt | WFO |
| 90.txt | SCA |
| 50.txt | SCA |
| 80.txt | SCA |
| 100.txt | SCA |

I want to define a dictionary based on which I can select some columns, but each file has its own code in the Voucher_stand column, how can I filter this DataFrame by dictionary based on Voucher_stand and file instead of using the list every time?

For example, define Voucher_Stand and files in a dictionary and then filter my DataFrame based on this dictionary:

```
code = {'90.txt':['SCA', 'SCB'], '60.txt':['WFA', 'WFO']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
pd.DataFrame(df.set_index('file').groupby('file')['Voucher_stand'].apply(list)).T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

You can get it in a `dict` form by calling `.to_dict()`:

```py
pd.DataFrame(df.set_index('file').groupby('file')['Voucher_stand'].apply(list)).T.reset_index(drop=True).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the dictionary using `items` and filter the desired rows using equal comparison for the key and [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for the list of `Voucher_stand` codes. Then, get the row's index as list and save it into a variable. Use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to select only those rows that match the criteria.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', sep='\s+')
print(df)

CODE = {'90.txt':['SCA', 'SCB'], '60.txt':['WFA', 'WFO']}

filtered_rows = []
for k,v in CODE.items():
    filtered_rows += df[(df['file'] == k) & df['Voucher_stand'].isin(v)].index.to_list()

result = df.iloc[filtered_rows]
print(result)
```

Output from *result*

```py
     file Voucher_stand
0  90.txt           SCA
1  90.txt           SCB
4  90.txt           SCA
2  60.txt           WFA
3  60.txt           WFO
```

Comment: in another example of this DataFrame, i use your code like this but get another answer:

https://s4.uupload.ir/files/1_3ijq.png

Comment: @amin-jebeli I don't see any reason not to work. The output from `c1` before `groupby` is as expected?

Comment: @n1colas-m
c1 does not work properly before groupby, it actually works well for the file 365-240, but for 240-180 it does not filter the code contained in the dictionary